# Data passed to Handlebars not showing

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, knex.js

I want to display items from the database which I already log the result to the console. The console displays the result. but handlebars not displaying data.

This is controller

```
exports.createCategory = function(req, res, next){
    knex('product_category')
    .select()
    .then(function(errors, result){
        res.render('administration/category', { result, errors });
    });
   }
```

This is my router

```
router.get('/category', adminControllers.createCategory);
```

and this is my handlebar

```
   <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
           {{#each result}}
           <h1>{{category_name}}</h1>
           {{/each}}
   </div>
```

Comment: What is the value of `result`? Is it an `object`, an array of primitives, an array of `objects`, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do debugging 101.

Add debug prints and check that you get correct data from DB and that it even executes.

Add to template some field to show you error too. Now if error is returned from query, nothing is shown.

Also add some static test attribute that you pass to template and print it to make sure that you are using handlebars template correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I later got it.

Its the knex query.

after studying the knex docs and some online resources, I discovered I can also do this

```
knex('table').then(function(result)){
res.render('/', {result});
}
```

but I don't why this didn't work

```
knex('table').select().then(function(result)){
res.render('/', {result});
}
```